# Stateless Widget not Updating with StreamProvider

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication, flutter-provider

I am trying to use StreamProvider to get my app to display the `Features` widget when a user is signed in. Here is my code:

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

import 'auth/auth.dart';
import 'features/features.dart';

void main() => runApp(
      StreamProvider<FirebaseUser>(
          create: (context) => FirebaseAuth.instance.onAuthStateChanged,
          child: MaterialApp(home: MyApp()),
          updateShouldNotify: (_, __) => true),
    );

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  static reload(BuildContext context) {
    Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MyApp()),
      (Route<dynamic> route) => false,
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var _user = Provider.of<FirebaseUser>(context);
    print('USER ISSUED: ' + _user.toString());
    if (_user == null) return SignInPage();
    if (_user != null) return Features();
  }
}
```

I had to create the `reload()` method, which is called by the various authentication widgets (google, facebook, password) nested below `SignInPage` to update display of `MyApp`. I would have expected that `Provider.of<FirebaseUser>` would rebuild my app automatically, without need to call `reload()`. The `Provider` does work. Whenever FirebaseAuth updates the user, it prints `USER ISSUED: some_user...`. Why does it not execute the next two lines of code to return either my `SignInPage` when `user == null` or the `Features` page when a user is logged in successfully?

I'm new to FlutterFire, but coming from AngularFire, I would have expected this to work smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be using:

```dart
// (firebase_auth 0.9.0)

StreamProvider.value(
    value: FirebaseAuth.instance.onAuthStateChanged,
    child: MaterialApp(home: MyApp()),
  ),
```

because as per the [docs](https://pub.dev/documentation/provider/latest/provider/StreamProvider-class.html) `StreamProvider.value` listens to `value` and expose it to all of `StreamProvider` descendants.

However, using `StreamBuilder` shall be preferred here as you might want to check if connection is established or not, else everytime the app opens it may show a glimpse of the login screen and then automatically go to the home screen in moderate network conditions, if user authentication is cached.

```dart
// (fireabse_auth 0.18.4)

StreamBuilder(
    stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
    builder: (_, snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
        return Loading();
      }
      if (snapshot.data is User && snapshot.data != null) {
        return Home();
      }
      return Authenticate();
    })
```

Also,

> I would have expected that Provider.of would rebuild my app automatically

It's `StreamProvider` that is responsible for listening to the stream, exposing it to the descendants and updating the consumer's state, and not `Provider.of<T>(context)`. `Provider.of<T>(context)` just attempts to access the data of type `T` from the nearest parent provider of `T`.